# If join exists then return value from join table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables with columns below

#### Inventory:

```
Id   Name    Price
 1   Item1    1€
```

And Table

#### InventoryPrices:

```
Id      Price
 1       2€
```

I want to select only one row for each item.
If join exists, then i need to select price from this 'InventoryPrices' else from my first table 'Inventory'. Till now if 'InventoryPrices' is joining with first table 'Inventory' it returns me two rows for each ID.

[image: Same IDs]

How can i check if join is not null then Show me one row with Second table price

Comment: I don't understand. If there is one row for the inventory ID 1 in `Inventory` and one row for inventory ID 1 in `InventoryPrices` and you join on inventory ID, you still have one result row not two. Please show your query.

Comment: In the example given by you, we don't have 2 records for each id in both the tables, then how are you getting 2 records for each id in output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if record exists in `InventoryPrices` table , you need to use `LEFT JOIN` To get only one row for each Id, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` like following query.

```
 SELECT   *             
         from
         ( 
                   SELECT    t1.id, 
                             t1.NAME, 
                             COALESCE(t2.price,t1.price) AS price ,
                             Row_number() OVER(partition BY t1.id ORDER BY t1.id) rn 
                   FROM      inventory t1 
                   LEFT JOIN inventoryprices t2 
                   ON        t1.id=t2.id 
     ) t 
WHERE    t.rn=1
```

Comment: In this example i am getting error syntax on after t1.id=t2.id ) t

Comment: Invalid column name 'rn'.

Comment: I forgot to move rn to inner table, I have corrected it, it should work now.

Comment: It work! Thank you, Does it work if i also use where statement?

Comment: Yes, you ca surly put any where condition, if you want to apply where on only selected column, in that case you can apply that on outer table, else you can always put where on your inner table query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188169/discussion-between-dim-and-psk).

Comment: Unfortunately it is blocked here for me

Comment: If i will use where statement it returns me only one row again.

Comment: What condition you are adding

Comment: after ON        t1.id=t2.id i am adding where t2.CatalogID =3 (CatalogID is another column in both of my tables)

Comment: You need to put this on "ON  t1.id=t2.id AND  t2.CatalogID =3" instead of where. If you want to filter records in left join, you need to put your condition on the join condition itself, not on the full where.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query:

```
WITH CTE_1 AS (

    SELECT T1.ID, T1.Name, 
    CASE WHEN T2.Price is NOT NULL THEN T2.Price ELSE T1.Price END as [Price], 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) as rn  
    FROM Inventory T1
    LEFT JOIN InventoryPrices T2 
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID)

 SELECT * FROM CTE_1 WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`outer apply` -- which implements something called a "lateral join" -- does exactly what you want:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, coalesce(t2.price, t1.price)
from t1 outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t2
      where t2.id = t1.id
     ) t2;
```

Normally, the subquery would have an `order by` to specify *which* price you want -- the smallest, oldest, newest, or prioritized by some other method.